# Finding the value of $p$ such that the two surfaces intersect along three different curves of intersection

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

Here's [a graph in GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/3d/x8vde2mm) as an optional accompaniment

Surface 1: $\theta$ $\in$ $[0,2\pi)$, $u$ $\in$ $ℝ$
$$x=\left(pu^{2}+R-r\right)\cos \theta$$
$$y=\left(pu^{2}+R-r\right)\sin \theta$$
$$z=u$$

Torus:  $\theta$,$u$ $\in$ $[0,2\pi)$
$$x=\left(R+r\cos\left(u\right)\right)\cos \theta$$
$$y=\left(R\ +r\cos\left(u\right)\right)\sin \theta $$
$$z=r\sin u$$

1. For what values of $p$ will these two surfaces intersect only along a circle in the plane $z=0$?
2. For what value of $p$ will these two surfaces intersect along three separate circles?
3. Denote the answer of question 2 as $p_0$. If $p=p_0$ then in what plane does each of the three curves of intersection reside in?

Remark: for $p<p_0$ there will be five different circles, each of which is a curve of intersection

---

Here is my answer to question 1:

Slice the two surfaces simultaneously with a plane containing the $z$-axis.

The resultant cross section is made up of two circles and two parabolas.

WLOG suppose we sliced the surfaces using the plane $y=0$.

Then as our parabola we have the curve

$$x=pz^2+R-r$$

We can then deduce that the curvature of this parabola at its vertex is $2p$

Let's call the point at which this vertex is located $I$

Setting this curvature equal to the circle's curvature at the point $I$ (which is $1/r$) we can then solve for $p$ and we get

$$p=\frac{1}{2r}$$

And thus, the answer to question 1 is

$$p≥\frac{1}{2r}$$

[Here in desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ouvzqmj4y7) I've set up a way to roughly see for yourself that it is only these $p$ values that will work.

[Here in desmos (2)](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/btpjkf0lua) I've set up a way to see the parabola's osculating circle and see the fact that only the $p$ values such that $p≥\frac{1}{2r}$ will work

---

Here's how I went about answering question 2.

[Here in desmos (3)](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/thsvon26le) you can see that if $p$ is a negative number with a sufficiently large absolute value than we can make the surfaces intersect along as many as five different curves of intersection

We can take the problem down by a dimension and concern ourselves with a parabola and a circle, and then concern ourselves with solutions of the following system of equations:

$$x=py^{2}+R-r$$
$$\left(x+R\right)^{2}+y^{2}=r^{2}$$

We want the value of $p$ to be such that the above system of equations has only two real solutions, rather than four real solutions.

For $p≠0$ this system of equations has the following solutions:

- $$x=\frac{-\sqrt{4p^2r^2-4pr+8pR+1}-2pR-1}{2p}$$ $$y=-\frac{1}{p}\sqrt{\frac{-\sqrt{4p^2r^2-4pr+8pR+1}+2pr-4pR-1}{2}}$$
- $$x=\frac{\sqrt{4p^2r^2-4pr+8pR+1}-2pR-1}{2p}$$ $$y=-\frac{1}{p}\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{4p^2r^2-4pr+8pR+1}+2pr-4pR-1}{2}}$$
- $$x=\frac{-\sqrt{4p^2r^2-4pr+8pR+1}-2pR-1}{2p}$$ $$y=\frac{1}{p}\sqrt{\frac{-\sqrt{4p^2r^2-4pr+8pR+1}+2pr-4pR-1}{2}}$$
- $$x=\frac{\sqrt{4p^2r^2-4pr+8pR+1}-2pR-1}{2p}$$ $$y=\frac{1}{p}\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{4p^2r^2-4pr+8pR+1}+2pr-4pR-1}{2}}$$

These four solutions will describe a total of only two unique solutions if we use a value of $p$ such that $$4p^2r^2-4pr+8pR+1=0$$

Solving for $p$, we get $$p=\frac{±2\sqrt{R\left(R-r\right)}+r-2R}{2r^{2}}$$

Testing these out in desmos, only $$p=\frac{-2\sqrt{R\left(R-r\right)}+r-2R}{2r^{2}}$$ actually works

Thus, the answer to question 2 is $$p=\frac{-2\sqrt{R\left(R-r\right)}+r-2R}{2r^{2}}$$

---

Now having the answer to question 2, answering question 3 is easy. We know that each of the planes is of the form $z=k$ for some real k.

One of the three curves of intersection is a circle in the plane $$z=-\frac{1}{p}\sqrt{\frac{2pr-4pR-1}{2}}$$
where $$p=\frac{-2\sqrt{R\left(R-r\right)}+r-2R}{2r^{2}}$$

One of the three curves of intersection is a circle in the plane $z=0$

One of the three curves of intersection is a circle in the plane $$z=\frac{1}{p}\sqrt{\frac{2pr-4pR-1}{2}}$$
where $$p=\frac{-2\sqrt{R\left(R-r\right)}+r-2R}{2r^{2}}$$

Here's a [final graph in desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ape2ggtqbu) with the answers to question 2 and question 3 in mind.